# Java "instanceof" to add over multiple lists

Tags: java, list, instanceof

I am currently trying to refactor my code after I read up that implementations are preferred over extensions. Currently, I am trying to create a function that adds an Object into a Scene. In order to better define what each object is, there are multiple Lists such as a list for updating, rendering, etc.

```
private List<Updatable> updatables;
private List<Removable> removables;
private List<Renderable> renderables;
private List<Collidable> collidables;
```

I want to make a function into my Scene class like so:

```
public void add(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Updatable)
        updatables.add((Updatable) o);
    if(o instanceof Removable)
        removables.add((Removable) o);
    if(o instanceof Renderable)
        renderables.add((Renderable) o);
    if(o instanceof Collidable)
        collidables.add((Collidable) o);
}
```

likewise I would create a similar remove function. My question is if this is bad coding practice since I have heard of the pitfalls of instanceof, and secondly if it is, is there a way around this / restructuring my code to make adding instances simple? I prefer not to have to add an instance to every list and define which ones it belongs to every time.

Comment: Lots of similar questions on this. [For instance](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+instanceof+code+smell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do similar with Factory pattern using `Map`

```
static Map<String, List> maps = new HashMap<>();
static {
    maps.put(Updatable.class.getName(), new ArrayList<Updatable>());
    maps.put(Removable.class.getName(), new ArrayList<Removable>());
    maps.put(Renderable.class.getName(), new ArrayList<Renderable>());
    maps.put(Collidable.class.getName(), new ArrayList<Collidable>());
}
public static void add(Object obj){
    maps.get(obj.getClass().getName()).add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use class 'Class' instead of class 'String' and then do: maps.put(Updatable.class, new ArrayList<Updatable>());? I think I will incorporate this way.

Comment: @MichaelChoi You should not accept an answer without having even tried it. This will throw NPE , because you have implementation classes for these interfaces, so `maps.get()` will return null. It also doesn't solve the problem of a class implementing more than one of the interfaces, as per your comment on my answer.

Comment: @EJP, the OP don't mention `Updateable` is class or interface, this code will update depend on use case and need do more on some negative cases when using `maps.get`. This just is one of ideas to suggest avoid `if` `else` to check `instance of`

Comment: @Jerry06 He has mentioned it subsequently, but my comment was addressed to the OP, not to you.

Comment: @EJP I did try the answer, but then I later realized that it didn't work. The main reason was because I couldn't figure out a way for java to figure out what class it was. I actually tried to modify the answer by doing "Map<Class, List> maps", but again, when I called "maps.get(Updatables.class).forEach(Update::update)" that's when I started getting issues.

Answer (score 2):

Just use overloads: `add(Updateable u), add(Removable r),` etc.

Comment: This seems like the more natural approach for Java.

Comment: Ah this is interesting. I did not know that this will call to every interface. This means that if I have an object which implements both updatable and removable, then both functions will be called? if this is the case which is called first.

Comment: Update: This way does not work for me unfortunately. When an object is both Updatable and Removable, then trying to add the object will cause an "ambiguous method call". This could be solved by casting so I would do scene.add((Updatable) obj); scene.add((Removable) obj); but that does not seem like an ideal solution.

Comment: @MichaelChoi Use an overload for the implementing class. For example, if you have a class Foo which implements both Updatable and Removable, then add an overload for Foo.

Comment: @MichaelChoi If you have objects that implement multiple of these interfaces, *nothing* will work, because the correct implementation is undefined. Which of those lists should it be added to?

Comment: @Sudicode I am not understanding what you mean by using an overload. If I have "class Foo implements A, B", then in class Scene I have "add(A a)" and "add(B b)", finally if I do "scene.add(foo)" then I get the ambiguous call error. I might be mistaken, but doesn't overloading just let you change the parameters of the method? I need foo to be added to both lists for A and B.

Comment: @MichaelChoi I'm saying should also have method "add(Foo f)". In the implementation of *that* method, you specify that you want Foo to be added to both lists. (This makes the compiler error disappear too.)

Comment: @Sudicode ah ok I understand. I don't think this is what I am looking for ,however, because I would not want to make an add function for tons of different objects and their different implementation combinations. thank you though.

Comment: @MichaelChoi You haven't answered my question, and until you do so it isn't possible to answer your question properly.

Comment: @EJP oh sorry, I meant to tag you in another comment explaining that I need the object to be added to multiple lists. I am being ambiguous because there will be different objects with different combinations of implementations. I want this add function to automatically add to each implementation list. thank you for your patience. also what do you mean by _nothing_ will work? I do in fact have objects with multiple interfaces btw as you have read.

Comment: Well I really meant that the answer you accepted won't work either. You could modify it to do so. Next question is why you need multiple lists at all.

Comment: @EJP oh that is true. I am using multiple lists because certain objects such as the controller are just Updatable, whereas other objects such as a background would be just Renderable. I don't want them all to have the same properties, especially when I use the interface Collidable so I can avoid wasting processing on objects that are like particles and such.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments, your use case is somewhat special. `Updatable`, `Removable`, `Renderable`, and `Collidable` are all *interfaces*. You have classes which implement one or more of these interfaces. Ultimately, you want your `add` method to add an object to each list of which interface it implements. (Correct me if any of this is wrong.)

If overloading would be too verbose, you can accomplish this with reflection, like so:

```
private List<Updatable> updatables;
private List<Removable> removables;
private List<Renderable> renderables;
private List<Collidable> collidables;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void add(Object o) {
    try {
        for (Class c : o.getClass().getInterfaces()) {
            // Changes "Updatable" to "updatables", "Removable" to "removables", etc.
            String listName = c.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + "s";

            // Adds o to the list named by listName.
            ((List) getClass().getDeclaredField(listName).get(this)).add(o);
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Handle it
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO Handle it
    }
}
```

But if you're going to use this approach, please note these caveats:

1. Reflection, by nature, is very prone to runtime errors.
2. You may run into issues if your hierarchy is more complex. For example, if you have `Foo implements Updatable, Removable` and also `Bar extends Foo`, then calling `getClass().getInterfaces()` on `Bar` will return an empty array. If this sounds like your use case, you may want to use [ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#getAllInterfaces-java.lang.Class-) from Apache Commons Lang instead.

Comment: for statement 2, is this because Bar is considered to not be implementing anything even though Foo is? or is it just that the ".getInterfaces()" function just returns no interfaces for child classes?

Comment: It's because `getInterfaces()` will only pick up interfaces that are directly referenced by implements. It won't bother traversing the class hierarchy, as Apache's `ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces(Class)` would. However, if you redundantly declare Bar class as `Bar extends Foo implements Updatable, Removable`, then `getInterfaces()` will pick those up.

Answer (score 0):

What I would expect is that you have a separate `add` method for each of these lists, like so:

```
public void addUpdatable(Updatable updatable) {
    updatables.add(updatable);
}

public void addRemovable(Removable removable) {
    removables.add(removable);
}

// and so on
```

The reason for this is that these are separate lists, and while the concern from the implementation perspective is to make the API elegant and slick, these efforts will affect clarity from the user's perspective negatively.

For instance, the misunderstanding (in EJP's answer comments) about what happens when an `Updatable` which is also a `Removable` is added shows this lack of clarity. Although you use similar terms for both your types and your state which makes it seem redundant, you should still make it clear which list (or part of the state) an item is added to.

In any case, it looks like you are struggling with a problem in its bigger scope. I think that it would be a good idea to invest more time toward understanding the bigger problem.

Comment: can you help me understand the problem? So is this a problem with the current design? I am trying to make a game at the moment. For each game loop I only want certain objects to perform certain functions, i.e. update, render, remove. Is this a bad solution to the problem? if so do you have an alternative. It seems like you are suggesting that each list should be separate after all, but then how will a class like Player be both updatable, renderable, and removable?

Answer (score 0):

From @Jerry06, the best way to add an instance to multiple lists of different types for me was using a magic list getter.

```
private Map<Class, List> maps = new HashMap<>();
```

'maps' is used to find whichever list you are looking for.

```
private <T> List<T> get(Class<T> c) {
    return maps.get(c);
}
```

instead of using maps.get, I just use get(SomeClass.class). The function above automatically converts it to the list with correct element type. I then was able to do:

```
    get(Updatable.class).stream().filter(Updatable::isAwake).forEach(Updatable::update);
```

instead of:

```
    updatables.stream().filter(Updatable::isAwake).forEach(Updatable::update);
```

I mostly wanted a structure like this so all the lists could be wrapped up nicely, and secondly so I could just say maps.add(SomeNewClass.class, new ArrayList()), then call it whenever I wanted.